# Why does my QGraphicsWidget disappear when it's bounding box is still in view?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicswidget

I have a QGraphicsWidget that represents a line on a map. The object disappears when a small portion of the bottom of the bounding rectangle moves out of the scene. It also disappears when part of the right side of it's bounding rectangle goes out of the scene. Below is a illustration of what is happening.

The green box is the bounding rect as drawn from the object's paint function.

[image: Object is visible]

Now I pan the scene so that only this much of the object is visible. It is still in view. However, if I pan any more to the right, the object disappears despite having half of it's bounding rect still in the viewport.

[image: Object will disappear if panned one more pixel right.]

The same thing happens when panning down so that the bottom of the object is leaving the viewport. If I pan any more down than below, the object disappears.

[image]

Here is the paint function:

```
void AirwayGraphicsWidget::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) {


    QPen pen(m_aw_obj->AltitudeType() == stds::rdb::WPAltitudeTypes::HIGH ? COLOR_HI_AIRWAY :
    m_aw_obj->AltitudeType() == stds::rdb::WPAltitudeTypes::LOW ? COLOR_LO_AIRWAY :
    COLOR_BOTH_AIRWAY);

    pen.setWidth(3);
    pen.setCosmetic(true);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawPolyline(m_points.data(), m_points.size());

    pen.setColor(m_is_hovered ? Qt::red : Qt::green);
    pen.setWidth(0);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
}
```

Any ideas about what is going on here? I've been messing with it for a couple of days and I'm out of things to try.

**Update**
Constructor

```
AirwayGraphicsWidget::AirwayGraphicsWidget(const stds::rdb::model::EnrouteAirway* aw, QGraphicsItem* parent)
: RDBEntityGraphicsWidget(aw, parent)
, m_bounding_rect()
, m_aw_obj(aw)
, m_lod(LevelOfDetail::NONE)
, m_is_hovered(false)
{

    double highest_lat = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
    double lowest_lat  = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double highest_lon = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
    double lowest_lon  = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    for (auto &awd : m_aw_obj->AirwayData()) {
        if (-awd.entity->Pos().latitude_deg > highest_lat) {
            highest_lat = -awd.entity->Pos().latitude_deg;
        }

        if (-awd.entity->Pos().latitude_deg < lowest_lat) {
            lowest_lat = -awd.entity->Pos().latitude_deg;
        }

        if (awd.entity->Pos().longitude_deg > highest_lon) {
            highest_lon = awd.entity->Pos().longitude_deg;
        }

        if (awd.entity->Pos().longitude_deg < lowest_lon) {
            lowest_lon = awd.entity->Pos().longitude_deg;
        }

        m_points.push_back(QPointF(awd.entity->Pos().longitude_deg, -awd.entity->Pos().latitude_deg));
}
    highest_lat += 5.0 * geom::NM_TO_DEG;
    lowest_lat  -= 5.0 * geom::NM_TO_DEG;
    highest_lon += 5.0 * geom::NM_TO_DEG;
    lowest_lon  -= 5.0 * geom::NM_TO_DEG;
    prepareGeometryChange();
    m_bounding_rect = QRectF(QPointF(highest_lon, highest_lat), QPointF(lowest_lon, lowest_lat));

    setPreferredHeight(m_bounding_rect.height());
    setPreferredWidth(m_bounding_rect.width());

    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
}

QRectF AirwayGraphicsWidget::boundingRect() const { return m_bounding_rect; }
```

Comment: show the boundingRect() method

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's quite a bit of code to get a qt application with a zooming panning graphicsview.

Comment: If you provide a [mcve], obviously I'm not talking about your entire project, but a minimal project that reproduces your problem and focuses only on the desired functionality that is complete at the same time, that is to say that you do not lack anything external to be able to executing it makes our lives easier, if you try hard you will get a quicker response, if you do not, you probably will not get any response, all efforts have their reward.